# In Python 2.7 what is difference between var1 = [list(range(6))] and var2 =range(6)?

Tags: python, python-2.7

In ex32 of LPTHW I found that I could make a list by doing this:

```
var1 = [list(range(6))]
```

or

```
var2 = range(6)
```

But, when I print var1 in a for-loop using '%d' I get a typeError saying it wants a number not a list. Meanwhile var2 **will** print using '%d'. How did I construct var1 to require a specific format specifier?

Comment: The simple option would be try it.

Comment: You can iterate through var1 by using a for-loop on var1[0].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake with `var1` is that you actually have a 2d `list`. By enclosing the entire thing in square brackets you are actually creating an external `list`, with a single element. This is the cause of your error, as that one element is a `list` also.

```
>>> list(range(6))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> [list(range(6))]
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Just get rid of the enclosing square brackets to make it work properly. Furthermore, as you are in Python 2, you don't need to do a `list` conversion, just do:

```
range(6)
```

Which was your second option all along. :)

Comment: And get rid of the call to `list` too, as `range` already returns a list.

Comment: @cbilliau If my answer was helpful to you, would you mind accepting it in about 15 minutes time? You can accept by clicking the tick below the vote counts so that it turns green. Thank you.

Comment: Why 15 minutes time? Is there a time limit on accepting I missed?

Comment: @confuzzledcoding632 There is a 15 minute grace period in which you cannot accept an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let's iterate through some cases:

### `range(6)`

This produces a list `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

### `list(range(6))`

`list()` expects an iterable object, and will transform that into a list. So `list(range(6))` takes the list returned by `range(6)`, and copies its members into a new list. So we get `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

### `[range(6)]`

This uses the python list creation syntax. This will take each argument inside the brackets, and place them into a list. So we would get: `[ [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] ]`. Note that this is a list of a list.

### `[list(range(6))]`

Here, we should know enough to know what happens. More or less, `range(6)`, and `list(range(6))` do the same thing, so we would expect the same result as the previous line, so we see: `[ [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] ]`.

### Notes about python3.x

Python 3 has attempted to make more lazy objects or iterators returned by builtins. So `range(6)` doesn't return a list in python 3.x. Instead, it returns a custom range object. This object can be converted into a list by doing `list(range(6))`, because it's iterable. However, if you don't need to mutate the returned object, then it probably makes sense to leave it as a range object.

Answer (score 0):

`var1 = [list(range(6))]` creates a list of a list, while `var2 = range(6)` creates a list.

```
>>> var1 = [list(range(6))]
>>> var1
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
>>> var2 = range(6)
>>> list(var2)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

When you include a variable in python within square brackets, it returns a list with the included variable as an element of the list:

```
>>> var3 = 1
>>> var4 = [var3]
>>> isinstance(var4, list)
True
```

So `list(range(6))` is all you need to be doing. It returns a list. Since you included that in square brackets by doing `[list(range(6))]`, you made it a list of a list.